# Serialize classes, that contain non serializable members

Tags: c#, serialization

Is there a possibility to serialize classes, that contain non-serializable members?

Example:
I have a class Instruction, which has two members:

```
public class Instruction
{
    public OpCode Op { get; set; }
    public object Operand { get; set; } 
}
```

The problem is, that the type of the member Op is in a 3rd party library and I can't make it serializable. I tried BinaryFormatter and ProtoBuf, but both failed without marking the Op-member.

Anyone knows a solution to serialize my object anyway?

Answer (score 3):

Obviously if a part of a class is not serializable, you can't serialize that part, but you can ignore it (and give some default, probably `null` value when deserializing).

You can use the `[ProtoIgnore]` attribute to mark the `Op` property if you are using `ProtoBuf`, or the `[NonSerialized]` attributes for `BinaryFormatter`.

Comment: But what when I need the member for later usage?

Comment: Well, you can't serialize something that isn't serializable. There's nothing much you can do about it without reverse engineering the classes and see how you can force serialization. Maybe the `OpCode` is using native resources?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to create a wrapper class over Opcode and use object of this wrapper class in  Instruction class for serialisation and other purposes in your application. In this way, you can get rid of any limitations with third party library.

Answer (score 2):

You could:

```
public class Instruction
{
    public OpCode Op { get; set; }

    public string OpString
    {
        get
        {
            return Op.Name;
        }

        set
        {
            Op = (OpCode)typeof(OpCodes).GetField(value, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase).GetValue(null);
        }
    }

    public object Operand { get; set; }
}
```

and disable serialization for `Op`. In this way you would serialize the `Name` of the op code (a `string`), and you would then be able to deserialize it.

With `BinaryFormatter` you could use the `ISerializable` interface and manually serialize:

```
[Serializable]
public class Instruction : ISerializable 
{
    public OpCode Op { get; set; }

    public object Operand { get; set; }

    public Instruction()
    {
    }

    public Instruction(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Op = (OpCode)typeof(OpCodes).GetField(info.GetString("Op"), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase).GetValue(null);
        Operand = info.GetValue("Operand", typeof(object));
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("Op", Op.Name);
        info.AddValue("Operand", Operand);
    }
}
```

Example of use:

```
var ins1 = new Instruction { Op = OpCodes.Add, Operand = (short)5 };
var ins2 = new Instruction { Op = OpCodes.Sub, Operand = 5.0 };

byte[] bytes;

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(ms, ins1);
    bf.Serialize(ms, ins2);
    bytes = ms.ToArray();
}

Instruction ins3, ins4;

using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    ins3 = (Instruction)bf.Deserialize(ms);
    ins4 = (Instruction)bf.Deserialize(ms);
}
```

If `Operand` can be something that isn't directly serializable, you can then create a surrogate of it inside the the `GetObjectData`.

Comment: Thats a possible way for the OpCode, but it wouldnt work for the object right? I mean, the operand can have multiple types.

Comment: @user See expanded response. Sadly protobuf doesn't support serializing primitive types (`int`, `short`, ...) inside an `object`